# Ruby class printing name in another class

Tags: ruby

```
class NameData
  def initialize
    @name="Cleetus"
  end

  class Greetings
    def hello()
      puts "Hello #{@name}! How wonderful to see you today."
    end
  end
end

greet=Greetings.new
p greet.hello
```

Im a little bit of a beginner, but i'm trying to get my name to be used in the Greetings class so the string will print with my name inside. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to put multiple classes inside the same module (sometimes called "namespacing") in Ruby, but it's unusual to have a class inside another class. Even if you do it's still a separate class and does not have access to instance variables in the "outer" class.

What you need to do is to make your `@name` value accessible outside your NameData object. The usual way to do this in Ruby is with an attribute reader:

```
class NameData
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize
    @name = "Cleetus"
  end
end

name_data = NameData.new
puts name_data.name
# => Cleetus
```

Once you've done that you need to tell your Greetings object about the NameData object, and how to use it. One way to do that is to pass the NameData object as an argument to `hello`:

```
class Greetings
  def hello(name_data)
    puts "Hello #{name_data.name}! How wonderful to see you today."
  end
end

greet = Greetings.new
greet.hello(name_data)
# => Hello Cleetus! How wonderful to see you today.
```

Another way is to pass it to the Greetings constructor and save it in an instance variable:

```
class Greetings
  def initialize(name_data)
    @name_data = name_data
  end

  def hello
    puts "Hello #{@name_data.name}! How wonderful to see you today."
  end
end

greet = Greetings.new(name_data)
greet.hello
# => Hello Cleetus! How wonderful to see you today.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@name` variable is an *instance variable* and it can not be seen by methods within a different class. It can only be seen by methods within the same class. Try this instead:

```
class Greetings
  def initialize
    @name="Cleetus"
  end

  def hello()
    puts "Hello #{@name}! How wonderful to see you today."
  end
end


greet = Greetings.new.hello
```